# heredoc script issue with gdb

Tags: shell, gdb, heredoc

I want to write a shell script to help me start gdb and input some commands which I don't want to input by myself, how should I do that?

I tried the heredoc below, but it doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

```
#! /bin/sh -
gdb ./myexe << MYHEREDOC
b xxx.c:1234
commands 1
printf "xxxxxxxx"
continue
end
MYHEREDOC
```

Thanks in advance for your kindly help~

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", you aren't telling us anything that will help us solve your problem.  HOW doesn't it work?  What happens when you run the script?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear, when I say "it doesn't work" I mean it doesn't stay in the gdb process, but jump out to the command line. I want this script to help me input some commands when the gdb software is launching.

Comment: Ah.  Then you want to use a script file, as @gvalkov said.  A here-document completely replaces the program's input with the contents of the document; when the document ends, it's as if you pressed control-D to send an EOF to the process, so it ends, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really should work (see [docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html)). Perhaps if you used a command file you could get away from having to use a heredoc:

*commands.gdb*:

```
file ./myexe
b xxx.c:1234
commands 1
printf "xxxxxxxx"
continue
end
run

$ gdb -x commands.gdb
```

Comment: Great tip, thank you, this could save me a lot of time, thank you very much for your help~